# Migrating data from public schema to table in another schema in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, schema, database-schema, data-migration

I need to migrate data from multiple tables in the db public schema to one table in a schema called fs. Then I need to match the migrated data, now is the fs schema, to data in a different table in the fs schema.

Would something like this work?

```
INSERT INTO targetTable
SELECT * FROM [sourceserver].[sourcedatabase].[dbo].[sourceTable]
```

Very new to postgreSQL and SQL in general, so please let me know if clarification is necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (<columns>)
SELECT <columns>
FROM schema.Table1
```